# Meaning of this hadith subtitle

Tags: hadith, arabic, translation

Chapter: “And We shall set up Balances of justice on the Day of Resurrection…”(58)
وَأَنَّ أَعْمَالَ بَنِي آدَمَ وَقَوْلَهُمْ يُوزَنُ وَقَالَ مُجَاهِدٌ الْقُسْطَاسُ الْعَدْلُ بِالرُّومِيَّةِ وَيُقَالُ الْقِسْطُ مَصْدَرُ الْمُقْسِطِ وَهُوَ الْعَادِلُ وَأَمَّا الْقَاسِطُ فَهُوَ الْجَائِرُ
Sahih al-Bukhari 7563
Narrated Abu Huraira:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "(There are) two words which are dear to the Beneficent (Allah) and very light (easy) for the tongue (to say), but very heavy in weight in the balance. They are: ''Subhan Allah wa-bi hamdihi'' and ''Subhan Allah Al-`Azim."
(see Hadith 6682).

I was wondering what the untranslated arabic part means: the part that starts with "the deeds of the son of Adam." Jazakullah Khair for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chapter: “And We shall set up Balances of justice on the Day of Resurrection…”(58) وَأَنَّ أَعْمَالَ بَنِي آدَمَ وَقَوْلَهُمْ يُوزَنُ وَقَالَ مُجَاهِدٌ الْقُسْطَاسُ الْعَدْلُ بِالرُّومِيَّةِ وَيُقَالُ الْقِسْطُ مَصْدَرُ الْمُقْسِطِ وَهُوَ الْعَادِلُ وَأَمَّا الْقَاسِطُ فَهُوَ الْجَا

And the deeds of son of Adam and their spoken words measure ( measure in the day of judgments), and Mujahid (Scholar name) said: القسطاس means justice in رومية (from Roman), and they said (it is known in Arabic that they say) “here is giving the root of the word” justice is the root of someone who act with justice (القسط) is the root of (المقسط). Which means عادل justice man or fair man ( sorry for my bad English I do not have much words to describe) . But the word القاسط means someone who is not just or fair. The word جائر means someone unfair.

Comment: Jazakullahu Khairun!